# Angular Material Chips Field Not Submitting in Form

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, angular-ngmodel

**Problem:**

I have a form, inside the form all fields are submitted correctly, however, the chips(aka tags in other frameworks) field(for technologies) does not get submitted.

**HTML:**

```
<!--MAIN CONTAINER-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <!--RESUME FORM-->
            <mat-card class="">
                <mat-card-content>
                    <form #resumeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(resumeForm)" class="m-3">
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-label>Full Name</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="resume.fullname" name="fullname" disabled="true">
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-label>Current Role</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="resume.currentRole" name="currentRole">
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="resume.email" name="email" disabled="true">
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
                            <textarea matInput [(ngModel)]="resume.description" name="description"></textarea>
                        </mat-form-field>

                        <!--TECHNOLOGIES FIELD-->
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-label>Technologies</mat-label>
                            <mat-chip-grid #chipGridTech>
                                <mat-chip-row *ngFor="let tech of techs" (removed)="removeTech(tech)">
                                    {{ tech }}
                                    <button matChipRemove>
                                        <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
                                    </button>
                                </mat-chip-row>
                            </mat-chip-grid>
                            <input #techInput matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="resume.technologies"
                                placeholder="add new technology..." [formControl]="techControl"
                                [matAutocomplete]="autoComplete" [matChipInputFor]="chipGridTech"
                                [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodesTech"
                                (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addTech($event)" name="technologies" />
                            <mat-autocomplete #autoComplete (optionSelected)="selectTech($event)">
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let tech of filteredTechs | async">
                                    {{ tech }}
                                </mat-option>
                            </mat-autocomplete>
                        </mat-form-field>

                        <!--CERTIFICATIONS FIELD-->
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-label>Certifications</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="resume.certifications" name="certifications">
                        </mat-form-field>

                        <!--WORK EXPERIENCE FIELD-->
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-label>Work Experience</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="resume.workExperience" name="workExperience">
                        </mat-form-field>

                        <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-label>Education</mat-label>
                            <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="resume.education" name="education">
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </mat-card-content>
            </mat-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Submit function:**

```
  submit(resumeForm: any) {
    console.log(resumeForm);
  }
```

**Console Log:**

[image]

**I tried:**

- Adding/Removing matInput
- Adding/Removing [(ngModel)]="resume.technologies"
- Adding/Removing name="technologies"

**Also I get this warning:**

[image]